# New wheel bearing makes more noise than before

Tags: dodge, wheel-bearing, grand-caravan

I purchased my own front wheel bearing hubs for my 2009 Dodge Grand Caravan. I had one installed, and then had the other one installed 5 days later. After the second one (right side) was installed I had it on the freeway and the humming sound was much louder than before. When I got over 75 mph it got even louder. Do I have a defective wheel bearing?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Very well could be ... have you taken it to where it was installed to see what they think?

Comment: No, I just noticed it today after they had closed. I will take it over tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few possibilities:

1. The bearing is defective: a bad bearing would cause noise
2. Badly installed bearing: if the mechanic installed the wrong bearing, installed it wrong, didn't grease it properly, etc then it would likely make noise. Whatever the mistake the bearing should be replaced with new as it could have been damaged
3. Something else is rubbing: to replace a bearing you have to take a lot of other stuff off, if it didn't all go on right something else could be rubbing, for instance on the wheel hub or the tire. If it's the tire make sure there's no sidewall damage that could impact safety

No matter what it needs to go back to the mechanic for sure.